# Parallel ForEach with SQL inserts c#

Tags: c#, foreach, ado.net, parallel.foreach

I have an object like the below but with a huge amount of data, we observed that it takes a long to be inserted into our SQL database as we were using normal `foreach`, the main idea is to insert each Department and get the generated identity number, then insert the nested employees assigned with that department ID.

```
<Sample>
    <Departments>
        <Department>
            <Name>HR</Name>
            <Employees>
                <Employee>
                    <Name>Marco</Name>
                </Employee>
                <Employee>
                    <Name>John</Name>
                </Employee>
                <Employee>
                    <Name>Sarah</Name>
                </Employee>
            </Employees>
        </Department>
        <Department>
            <Name>IT</Name>
            <Employees>
                <Employee>
                    <Name>Ali</Name>
                </Employee>
                <Employee>
                    <Name>Roberto</Name>
                </Employee>
                <Employee>
                    <Name>Franco</Name>
                </Employee>
            </Employees>
        </Department>
    </Departments>
</Sample>
```

We tried to use `Parallel.ForEach` to enhance the performance, and it does, but we got another issue with `@@IDENTITY` because there is an overlap between the running tasks in Parallel.ForEach as we found an employee is assigned to another department.

**The need** ... I need to speed the process up either I use `Parallel.ForEach` or `foreach` ... any ideas?

BTW ... we are calling a stored procedures which contains normal `INSERT INTO` command using classing `ADO.NET`

Comment: Parallel executions of SQL need their own connection and transaction. If you need to contain everything in one transaction you might look into `TransactionScope` as well.

Comment: Don't use `@@IDENTITY`. 99% of the time you wanted `SCOPE_IDENTITY` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` won't solve the problem of executing multiple SQL's in parallel through the same connection, but the advice is solid, `@@IDENTITY` is wrong by default.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, so, you advise to avoid `@@IDENTITY` but what is the replacement, in addition, do you think that if I went through single connection for each loop, this will solve the isuue ?

Comment: You may find this explanation useful, of why to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/6_Different_Ways_To_Get_The_Current_Identity_Value

Comment: @TyCobb already said what to use, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but this solves a different problem. However, if you're executing multiple SQL's in parallel through the same connection you will still risk mixing identity values being returned.

Comment: @TyCobb, as I have mentioned, just wanna speed the process up as the current object which I have takes about 7 minutes to be inserted into the database, then I tried using `Parallel.ForEach` which actually helped me well to solve the performance issue, but it caused issues in the data insertion because of IDENTITY issue

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, actually each `INSERT` runs with its own `SqlConnection`, but after calling the SP of the insertion, we are executing `SELECT @@IDENTITY` separately because the same SP is used by another components in the system .. do you have any solutions or ideas for the same?

Comment: inserting into your big table would require index to be reordered each time new row is inserted. you might want to consider inserting all your data into a temp table and then merge those into your main table. OR you can just build a huge multi insert statement like INSERT INTO XXX VALUES(1), (2), (3)

Comment: And parallel foreach might not help you if your bottleneck is on the DB side. Instead it might even generate more overhead and slows you down.

Comment: You posted zero code to address the problem.

Comment: @paparazzo, it's about the idea, not the code ... I pointed to simple code scenarios, I am just thinking about the idea and the approach which I should go through

Comment: Well it should be about the code.  Pretty sure you have some really bad code.

Comment: Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, if that doesn't solve your problem you will need to rewrite your stored procedure as then it must be inserting into multiple tables. But as others have said, you really should post some code. The idea is sound, the implementation might be flawed but we have no way of knowing this, so we're left with guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use guid as primary key into your table. It would help you to avoid problem with @@IDENTITY. 
At first you should generate new guid-identity, thank insert the generated value into a  row